# update an ahref url without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have an online store, and the view cart page has a "promo code" field, where a user can enter a code and get 10% off.  however, the url i send is on the same page and thats how i send data to my cc auth folks. how can i change the variable $totalOrderCost in the url without refreshing the page?

```
 $('#promoCodeSub').click(function(){

  var promoVal = $('#promoCode')val();
  //update url by $totalOrderCost x promoVal  ....

 });
echo "<tr><td>Promo Code</td><Td><input type='text' name='promoCode' id='promoCode'></td></tr>";
```

the url:

```
 <a href='https://someServer/sale?&UMamount=" . $totalOrderCost . "&UMinvoice=" .  $_SESSION['userId'] . "'><img src='checkout.gif'></a>
```

edit for answer 1:

```
 $('#promoCodeSub').click(function(){

    $('a#ccHref').attr('href').replace('http://google.com');
    alert($('a#ccHref').attr('href'));
 //still shows original url.
 });

 <a href='https://someServer/sale?&UMamount=" . $totalOrderCost . "&UMinvoice=" .  $_SESSION['userId'] . "' id='ccHref'><img src='checkout.gif'></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to get the anchor tag in question and replace the amount in the href attribute dynamically.

Something along these lines should work:

```
$("a#checkoutLink").attr("href", $("a#checkoutLink").attr("href").replace(/UMamount\=[0-9]{1,}/, "UMamount=" + value));
```

working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/U8p3j/2/

Comment: From the looks of it your anchor tag is being output by PHP, with the total order cost and other information appended to the url.  You want to grab that anchor tag and change the `UMamount` value in the url to the updated amount on the client side (php is server side).  My suggestion won't work without you putting a unique ID on the anchor tag and using it in place of `#myAnchor` in the code.

Comment: added working fiddle to answer for reference of how this should all work.

Comment: hmm the fiddle works, only the first time though.  enter value in input, it works, enter again, it doesnt update. we are on the right track ;)

Comment: It works every time for me... not sure how to help you further.

Comment: mouseover the actual url and see what url the browser thinks you will be going to.  your span updates perfectly.  the actual url itself doesnt.

Comment: Works every time for me no matter what.  Regex updated to grab any value up to the next url variable.  New fiddle added to answer.